# Wordpress - Adding custom Templates for Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, posts

I'm using different page-templates this for pages.

Now I need the same for posts.

Since 4.7 this should be a core functionality.

So I pretty much followed [this quick tutorial](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/) and added a custom `single-duplicate.php` in my theme folder and added this code at the top:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Full-width layout
Template Post Type: post, page, product
*/
```

However upon creating a new post I dont see the "Post Attributes" Box with the Template-dropdown. What do I do now? Is it possible that my theme somehow prevents that?

Here's my themes [functions.php](https://gist.github.com/NilsDannemann/bdb064315644b263cae81d36ff6b323e) as a gist, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused as to what Page Attributes will give you access to. To the best of my knowledge, you do not get a drop down to choose a template (as you do on Pages) as an automatic function on posts/custom post types.

you need to create a single-{POSTTYPE}.php in your theme directory and need to add/follow the HTML structure of your page template.

For more information,

- [Custom Post Type page template doesn't show up](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47188/custom-post-type-page-template-doesnt-show-up)
- [Post Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files)

Hope this will helps you.